# Using BETWEEN or <=, >= for Oracle timestamps

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

My Oracle table has a column `tmstp` with the `TIMESTAMP(3) WITH TIME ZONE` datatype.

When I run the following query

```
SELECT COUNT(column1) 
  FROM table1 
 WHERE tmstp BETWEEN to_timestamp_tz('10-OCT-10 05.00.00.000000000 AM -05:00', 'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR')
                 AND to_timestamp_tz('11-OCT-10 04.59.59.999999999 AM -05:00', 'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR');
```

it gives about twice the count as the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(column1) 
  FROM table1 
 WHERE tmstp >= to_timestamp_tz('10-OCT-10 05.00.00.000000000 AM -05:00', 'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR') 
   AND tmstp <= to_timestamp_tz('11-OCT-10 04.59.59.999999999 AM  -05:00', 'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR');
```

I thought they should give equivalent results. Any input on what might be happening? How should I debug this?

Comment: what version of oracle are you using?

Comment: Just a comment: Use `count(1)` instead; it's much faster for oracle.

Comment: Can you give an example of a row that would satisfy (condition 1) and not (condition 2): `SELECT tmstp FROM table1 WHERE (condition1) AND NOT (condition2) AND rownum = 1`

Comment: @Aaron: `count(1)` and `count(column1)` are not equivalent *in general*. They will give the same result if and only if `column1` is not null on all rows of the result set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry for the trouble. I figured it out. My question is actually flawed too because I edited it to hide confidential data.

There was an extra whitespace between the AM and timezone offset in one of the queries and that caused different results.

Stupid me.

So if the timestamp string that is converted is a bit off with whitespaces, the answers might be off.

Comment: +1 One more reason not to use the built-in data type conversion routines :-)

Comment: I can't reproduce this in 12.1.0.2.  This might have been a bug in 10g.